# android button and sound array with mediaplayer

Tags: android, arrays, button, media-player

I have a soundboard that I am trying to clean up with better code. Here is a sample, my actual program has over 40 buttons so I want to avoid repetitive code by implementing an array but I'm not sure how can I achieve this? Any idea will be appreciated!

```
namespace soundrelease

{
[Activity (Label = "soundrelease", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button button1 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button1);
        Button button2 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button2);

        button1.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {

            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.sound01);
            mediaPlayer.Completion += mediaPlayer_Completion;
            mediaPlayer.Start();
        };

        button2.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {

            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.sound02);
            mediaPlayer.Completion += mediaPlayer_Completion;
            mediaPlayer.Start();
        };

    }
    void mediaPlayer_Completion(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MediaPlayer mp = (MediaPlayer)sender;
        mp.Completion -= mediaPlayer_Completion;
        mp.Release();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're looking to do more clearly? You want to avoid rewriting code with a loop, what do you want the loop to achieve?

Comment: I basically just want to have one method to handle clicking a button and have it play the corresponding sound, instead of having to repeat the button click event 40 times for all the buttons.

I tried something like this but I'm getting some errors
http://i.gyazo.com/4666f5f2ea4d1433b623ef5e412e3ea3.png

Comment: you can try to add track in the button's tag, when any button is clicked  [ knowing that getTag will return an audio track ] call player.play(button.getTag()). the method create require Context + id